# multiple median or mean points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

I am using ArcMap 10.3. In my map there are resources, and I want to find the location which minimize the distance between them. If I use the Mean or Median Center weighted on the resource I find just one point. Is there any tool in which I can find 2, 3 points which minimize the distance?

Comment: Maybe you could try some clustering methods. Check Spatial Statistics toolbox, Mapping Clusters toolset. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/an-overview-of-the-mapping-clusters-toolset.htm